# Do I need a visa to organise and run a conference in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel, conferences

I work for an Australia-based company. We run training programs in Australia, but we also consult to international companies.

We want to run a training program for our international clients, and hold a face-to-face workshop in the UK.

Payment will be received from the participants to attend this workshop. Is there a visa that will allow us to travel to the UK and provide training to these participants?

Comment: Are you supplying some to your UK customer's - product or service - of which the training is a part? Or is the training the thing you are selling?   Does your company have a UK agent or subsidiary?

Comment: Hi DJ - thanks for your comment. We are an Australian company with no UK agent or subsidiary. We are not selling any product or service, the training program is what we are selling (e.g. client pays $x to participate in a 12-month course, some of which is delivered face to face in the UK).

Comment: Your staff member would effectively be in the UK doing the job of a teacher then.

Answer (score 1):

A training program can be viewed as both a product and service. More precisely, it is a business and to be able to conduct all or any portion of it in the UK, for a fee or gratis, requires a visa, such as:

[Tier 1 (Entrepreneur) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur)

[Tier 1 (Investor) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-investor)

[Work Visa](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas) (which require a Certificate of Sponsorship from an authorized entity).

It would be best to consult a solicitor which you can locate through the [UK Law Society](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/).